# Gulp: sass file was taken for the sourcemap

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have the following error in `styles` task:

```
(node:36040) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
(rejection id: 1): Error: "/framework/styles/_crossbrowser.sass" is not in the SourceMap.
```

The is no error on sourcemaps initialization step; below code working properly:

```
gulp.task('styles', () => {
    return gulp.src(/* Source path definition ... */)
        .pipe(gulpIf(isDevelopment, sourcemaps.init()))
        .pipe(sass())
        //.pipe(gulpIf(isDevelopment, sourcemaps.write()))
        // ...
```

The error appars if to try to write sourcemaps:

```
.pipe(gulpIf(isDevelopment, sourcemaps.write()))
```

I just imported some dependences in .sass file, it imports correctly if do not write sourcemaps:

```
@import "../../../framework/styles/_crossbrowser"
@import "../../../framework/styles/_framework"
```

The meaning of error is right: `_crossbrowser.sass` really is not the SourceMap. But why I got this error?

Answer (score 0):

Currently (`"gulp-sass": "^4.0.1"`) everything works.